# Cafe wifi DNS hijacking and kops validate cluster

Tags: dns, kops

I have created kops cluster many times before (on office internet connection) and have not changed my cluster config.
Only thing i am doing different now is trying to work from a cafe wifi.

`kops validate cluster` gives the error:
`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup api-REDACTED.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host`

I have found this [discussion on kops github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/1386) which seems to suggest DNS just takes time to propagate, maybe 15 minutes or more.
But my experience (working in office internet environment) suggests that kops and aws does not take so long to register and create the cluster.

I am not too familiar with DNS, I am thinking it might be due to cafe wifi having a different DNS?
I have read that

> Some DNS providers practice DNS hijacking while processing queries, redirecting web browsers to an advertisement site operated by the provider when a nonexistent domain name is queried.
>   From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Public_DNS

Which seems to make sense since this Starbucks periodically throws me out of the wifi connection and *serves me some latte ads*.

What is the workaround for this?  Can I make my wifi connection not DNS-hijacked in a cafe wifi setting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use secure DNS servers eg. `1.1.1.1` from cloudflare.
Regular DNS servers work over UDP protocol which is unencrypted and open, whereas the secure DNS servers from cloudflare works over TCP and uses HTTPS so that your DNS resolution queries are not read and manipulated on the wire.

Comment: thanks, i modified the /etc/resolv.conf to use `nameserver 1.1.1.1`. We'll see how it goes if my connection gets hijacked still..

Comment: been working awhile now and it seems after the ns change it doesn't kick me out anymore